# How to correctly run a single JavaScript file in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-devops

Tried to Google around, but seems I cannot find anything that tells how to run a single JavaScript file in Azure Pipeline with YAML. As I am learning JavaScript I want to do automations in JavaScript to practice, no matter how weird it would sound. Would appreciate your answer folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps below to set up your YAML pipeline to run the single JavaScript file:

1. At first, ensure the **`Node.js`** tool has been installed on the agent machine. Normally, the [MS hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software) have the latest version of Node.js tool pre-installed. In the pipeline job, you also can use the [**Node.js tool installer task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/node-tool-v0?view=azure-pipelines) (**`NodeTool@0`**) to install the latest or specified version of Node.js tool to the agent machine.
2. Then, you can use a command task (such as [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines)) to call the following **`node`** command to run the single JavaScript file.

   ```bash
   node path/to/JavaScript/file.js
   ```

---

##### Below is an example as reference.

- JavaScript file: `JavaScriptDemo/test-loop.js`

```js
var index = 0;
while (true) {
  console.log(`Current index is`, index);
  
  if (index == 5) {
    break;
  }
  
  index++;
}
console.log(`The final index is`, index);

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(`Current i is`, i);
}
```

- YAML Pipeline: `azure-pipelines.yml`

```yaml
. . .

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      displayName: 'Use the latest Node.js'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '>=6.x'
        checkLatest: true
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Run a single JavaScript file'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo "Run the JavaScript file: JavaScriptDemo/test-loop.js"
          node JavaScriptDemo/test-loop.js
```

- Result
  [image]